# Hiding Draft Post In Admin

Tags: posts, wp-query, customization, draft

Does anyone know of a way to hide draft post so that when "All" post is selected, draft post is not included?

I tried adding this code to my functions.php file but it lead to an error, I'm assuming it's because this code was written for a previous version of WordPress.

Is the code below the correct code I should be using?

```
// Add a query argument to the Posts admin menu.
// This is used to ensure that we only apply our special filtering when needed.
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse255311_admin_menu', PHP_INT_MAX );
function wpse255311_admin_menu() {
    global $menu, $submenu;

    $parent = 'edit.php';
    foreach( $submenu[ $parent ] as $key => $value ){
        if ( $value['2'] === 'edit.php' ) {
            $submenu[ $parent ][ $key ]['2'] = 'edit.php?all_posts=1';
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Hide draft posts from All listing in admin.
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse255311_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse255311_pre_get_posts( $wp_query ) {
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    // Ensure the the all_posts argument is set and == to 1
    if ( ! isset( $_GET['all_posts'] ) ||  $_GET['all_posts'] != 1 ) {
        return;
    }

    // Bail if we're not on the edit-post screen.
    if ( 'edit-post' !== $screen->id ) {
        return;
    }   

    // Bail if we're not in the admin area.
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Ensure we're dealing with the main query and the 'post' post type
    // Only include certain post statuses.
    if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() && $wp_query->query['post_type'] === 'post' ) { 
        $wp_query->query_vars['post_status'] = array (
            'publish',
            'private',
            'future'
        );
    }  
}
```